What should our logo and site design look like?
Another one of the The 7 Essential Questions of Every Beta. Quoting the blog post:

.5. What should our logo and site design look like?
This one is pretty straightforward. Solicit contributions, throw out ideas, post
  preliminary (or finished) designs, and be supportive and respectful of
  other people’s ideas and creativity.
We have designers on staff who will actively help come up with site
  designs but, if an idea stemming from the community stands out as
  exceptional, we are happy to use it.

So, go ahead, post your ideas and let us comment and vote on them.

A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our designers from last week: Custom Bitcoin design and logo - Information gathering :)

Update: Your new site design is live!

Here's my (doubtless controversial) offering 
Colour scheme
It may be worth paying attention to some of the information provided in this Colour Assignment article. 
The following combination has the following apparent properties:

light blue - associated with trust, reliability, technology and finance
gold - associated with wealth and prosperity
black - associated with quality, authority and technology

Interestingly, the shade of orange used by the standard Bitcoin logo is considered by many to be their least favourite colour.
Logo
A gold Bitcoin with just 0s and 1s around the border based on this:

I'm undecided about having the currency symbol in the middle. I think we could easily do without it, but it may affect recognition.
Strapline considerations
Some of it distilled from this forum discussion

No Latin since it comes across as being pompous
No "In X we trust" since it comes across being US centric

Offerings:

"Strength in numbers"  - my personal favourite
"A new type of money" 
"Money grows on Merkle trees" - joke! 


Well, if we look at the official site and StackOverflow side-by-side it almost seems as if they were built by the same designer. StackExchange sites seem to be fairly minimalist and clean, which reflects a certain image - mainly that the content is more important than the choice of background image. There is a professional and educated elegance to white/light backgrounds and mostly monochrome interfaces and this also allows splashes of color to truly stand out so long as they are sparingly used.
In fact, it seems that most of the various StackExchange sites are essentially StackOverflow clones with slight changes to the color scheme, which helps tie the disparate sites together as a community and I for one think we would do well to continue this trend.
For color scheme I recommend we continue the use of pastel blues typically seen on the various official Bitcoin sites and our "color shocks" should be the bright orange of the official logo. Links and other elements deemed important but not worthy of "bright orange status" can use a darkened gold color which ties in quite nicely to certain features of the client and other common Bitcoin icons and logos - the color of the links on the "sketchy" theme we're currently using would work quite nicely actually.
Another important consideration is the logo. The default Bitcoin logo might work well enough, though it doesn't seem to "fit in" with many of the other StackExchange site logos. Glancing down the list, though, I do see a few logos that we could say the same of so perhaps that's not as big an issue as I first thought.

Yeah, I think that the default Bitcoin logo will work just fine.

We may want to have a modified logo anyway.  People tend to complain when Bitcoin sites just use the "default", as it becomes hard to tell browser tabs apart.

Yeah the favicon should be different, so I suppose if we want the favicon to match the logo then we need a custom logo.

I would definitely try to stick with blue where appropriate since it is associated with trust.

David Perry's answer suggests that we stick to general StackExchange design with minor changes, while it's certainly the path of least resistance there is also good examples of custom design, eg apple.stackexchange.com . We can start bounty and people like Eli, developer of Safebit Bitcoin Client, would be able to make the site look great.

+1 for designers to be involved in this. The Gaming SE design is also very cool.

My only argument is that in both cases presented, there is already a well-known aesthetic which is being mimicked in the site design. Bitcoin has no well-known aesthetic aside from a few well-known icons which we probably shouldn't use because everyone complains about their overuse.

How about a logo that is composed of a Bitcoin and a question mark?

Could work. Someone with graphics skills, post a suggestion!

I disagree. That immediately made me think that Bitcoin wasn't viable for some reason.

Now that you say it, I think I agree.

How about a logo consisting of bitcoin symbol and some symbology that implies exchange.
I was thinking something like bitcoin incom surrounded by circular arrows similar to recycling symbol.
Recycling Symbol:

But maybe something more like this:

or this (the one in upper right)

Maybe a modified version similar to arrwo in he bottom example but two "half arrows" each making their way halfway around the bitcoin icon.
These are just examples I found searching google images just kinda brainstorming ideas at this point.  The concept of using imagery to imply "exchange" both Bitcoin as a medium of exchange and the exchange of ideas.
